# How to let dart print unhandled exception to file instead of stderr?

Tags: android, flutter

We want to collect log while the app is not in a development environment. We can use Logger to send log to a file. But there are also many unhandled exceptions we would like to see. By default these errors are printed into stderr, is there a way to change that to output them into a file so we can check (I mean with Android, you have more access for file system).